# Excel sorting random table after specified column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

*issue*

- My data is being generated in the form of table 1, as the company lists are provided in a random order.
- However, I wish to sort the data in table 1, to match the format of table 2, such that it matches with the company lists as shown in the excel example.

*what I have tried*

I have tried using `Index` and `Match`functions, without success.

*image*

The attached photo shows a list of companies, in a specific column with a specific order, named "Company lists"

[image]
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this screenshot the formula in cell G3 is

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$3:C$12,$A3),$A3,"")
```

copied across and down.

[image]